# Run WebDriver in different browsers (firefox, chrome, ie) in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am new to WebDriver as well as Java. I want to write a testcase which will run in Firefox. Chrome and IE in parallel (may be using thread).

My initial concept:
Step 1: Create an Arrary List having three types of object (FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver and InternetExplorerDriver)
Step 2: In a loop : for each driver in Arrary List run the testcase in parallel

Can you please help me out using some sample codes or may be some useful links? Or is there any different approach to achieve my requirement?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [testNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) framework with which you can run your tests in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want run the same tests on different browsers at the same time parallely, you need to use Selenium Grid + TestNG. Refer [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) for Selenium Grid and check Grid2 details.

Answer (score 0):

Below link may address your question.

http://goo.gl/VkIBFr